# Codeigniter RESTful API returning invalid JSON

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, rest

I'm using the RESTful API from Codeigniter. So I when i try to run this:

```
<?php

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class artists extends REST_Controller{

    public function letter_get($letter)
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = "SELECT artist_id, formated_name FROM artists WHERE formated_name LIKE '".$letter."%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();

        if($data) {
            $this->response($data, 200); 
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'Couldn\'t find any artists with that letter!'), 404);
        }
     }
}
?>
```

It returns invalid JSON with no closing tag. So the JSON looks like `[{....` but it doesnt close it with `}]`

I tried to do encoding with `UTF8` and `UTF8 without BOM` but without luck. It works when I do `LIMIT 0,100` in the sql-query but I dont want that.

So, can anyone halp me out? I'm super lost right now...

**[UPDATE]**

I tried to run it through http://jsonlint.com and I got this result:

```
Parse error on line 3872:
..."formated_name": "Lzy
 -----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: **`var_dump($data)`** and attach it with you question.

Comment: ok `var_dump($data)` actually gives `[{"artist_id":"2379","formated_name":"Butcher Babies"},{"artist_id":"2380","formated_name":"Butterfly Boucher"}]` when I put the var_dump before the `if`-statement - when I do it after the `if` statement it doesnt close the JSON

Comment: Does anyone have an idea???